# trigger for LayoutDirection for android

Tags: android, xml, layout, right-to-left

What is the trigger for application to determine which layout direction to use ?

my application was LTR by default for all devices and suddenly on RTL devices is mirroring the xml .

What could be the reason for that ? i want all my layout to be the same regardless to device language .

Comment: try android:supportsRtl="false" in Manifest

Comment: did that , did not work , i had to go over all my layout file and set layout direction to ltr and this solved my problem . but it is not a solution i like , i prefer to understand what happened suddenly